# Is there any way for me to check or find out the code that produced the dataset?

Tags: r

While practicing, I made the mistake of writing and running the code in the console instead of on the script. However, I managed to save all my work and datasets on the environment to work with on new sessions.

Right now I'm trying to rehash what I did on the last session. But since I didn't save the script from the last session, I don't know the codes that produced certain data set.

Is there any way for me to check or find out the codes?

Comment: Check if you have a file `.Rhistory` in your home directory, `Sys.getenv("R_USER")`.

Comment: In general, no. The objects you create in R do not remember how they were created. If you are using RStudio you can also check the history panel located usually in the top right panel. But if it's not in your history, then the code you typed in the console is gone. That's why it's always best to write code in script files rather than the console directly.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I tried looking at the .Rhistory file and found it. Thank you!